# What is the purpose of these spare rings for an HVAC blower motor?

Tags: hvac, electric-motor

I recently replaced the blower motor and wheel for our HVAC unit. The motor came with four of these spare rings:
[image: Blower Rings]

There is already an identical ring attached around what I would call the front shaft (spindle?) bearing. You can see it here:
[image: Blower motor shaft]

(This shot doesn't show the split.)
If it's some sort of shipping retainer, why would there be extras? And if this ring can become dislodged and fall off, thus requiring spares, this is a serious problem, as this ring being tossed around inside the blower wheel while it's running could probably do serious damage. This leads me to believe that this is not their purpose, either. So just what purpose do these spare rings serve?

Comment: the rings are to make the motor mounts of a 48 frame motor adapt to a frame 56 base. If the old motor was a frame 48 and the replacement is the same, you do not need the rings. If the base was originally for a 56 frame motor then you slip these rings onto the ends of the motor before installing. (1 per end)  If your motor does not fit into a base or if you don't them , then you discard them.

Comment: Okay, this sounds reasonable. But just to clarify: these bands DO NOT go between the belly band and the motor housing, right? (It doesn't seem like it would add enough space to accommodate the ½ inch difference in radius.)

Comment: No they would only be used for a base mount motor, Just like the older style motors that use drive belts.

Comment: @d.george, Thanks. Why don't you post your comment as an answer so that this can be marked as answered?

Comment: What is the difference between an answer and a comment? I am not that big on format  and how  would it be marked as answered. I probably need to find out how to handle both and where on this site do you find this information. Also I do not know how to grade answers, delete answers, etc. My biggest concern is all the dumb questions people ask. I am not judging, it is that people seem to ask the silliest questions that have nothing to do with the question being answered.

Comment: @d.george, if one were to search this SE community for unanswered questions, this one would show up. If you post your comment as an answer, I could then mark it as answered. I could post your answer myself, but that seem dishonest and deceitful to me. But I agree that as far as information goes, a comment and an answer are equivalent.

Comment: Comments can contain answers, but remember that we are building a database here and some people won't read the comments.  I have found answers to questions that were posted 5 years ago, and often the answer I need is in the comments.  SO I highly suggest that if you have commented with an answer and you decide it would make a good official answer then by all means go ahead and post it as an answer.  The best answers are formatted like this Q.  This is a very informal SE so your answer doesn't have to look perfect.  But it is better for future users if the correct answer is posted as such.

Comment: Bill is correct.  In fact, that is how I found it.  I clicked on unanswered and it was second on the list.  This is a question just begging for an answer.  And I see that it is in the comments.  To @d.george, what Bill is asking you to do is post your answer so he can show his gratitude by upvoting and accepting it, thus awarding you reputation points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Credit for this answer to user [d.george](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/63004/d-george), who has not responded since posting as a comment.  I'm posting as an answer so this question can be closed and marked answered.)

The rings are to make the motor mounts of a 48 frame motor adapt to a frame 56 base. If the old motor was a frame 48 and the replacement is the same, you do not need the rings. If the base was originally for a 56 frame motor then you slip these rings onto the ends of the motor before installing. (1 per end) If your motor does not fit into a base or if you don't them , then you discard them.

Comment: We can finally get this marked as answered.